# int or long variable types for long term scalability

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-design, scalability

I'm building an app and for several of my DB fields, I'm currently using an int, and same for the classes that define the object models that use these value.

Later (ie. 1-2 years, may be less I hope), I'll probably exceed 2 billion entries. Will it be a relatively big deal to change the data types then or should I take 20-30 minutes to change all the DB fields and classes from int to long now, while it's pretty easy to do.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If you're even considering this so early in development, just do it now and move on to something more interesting.

Comment: If you expect to exceed 2G then do it now. The longer you wait the more breaking changes you'll have later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that many rows in the table, upgrading to a 64-bit int from a 32-bit int may be a very slow operation, as it would cause a great deal of re-paging. Now, it would be a quick change. However, obviously your disk space usage would grow more quickly in the intervening period if you go straight to 64-bit fields now. If you can bear the cost of this in your plans, it would be worth doing now.

Comment: I'm going to be deploying in Azure btw. Looks like going for a long might be better to do now.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean int64 versus int32, then if you think you will need it and you have the resource get it done.

Being .net you can't implicitly cast from Int64 to int32, so compile will pick those up, you will need to look for any explicit casts you already do though.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for an Id field, you should consider using Guid which in theory should be more than enough

Comment: Why GUID? Just because its range is **HUGE**? `int` can contain `2147483647` values if you start with `0`. `bigint` has up to `9223372036854775807`, again ignoring *half* of its range. That data type is enough to comfortably hold the current US deficit, which is about the biggest number anyone can comprehend.

Comment: @Yuck you mean there are people that can comprehend that deficit?

Comment: @Yuck: The answer to "why use a globally unique identifier (guid)?" is *because I intend the identifier to be globally unique*. Use the right tool for the job. If you need a globally unique identifier, use the type explicitly designed for that task.

Comment: @EricLippert I guess that was my point - `integer` data has already been determined as the right tool for the job. It's just a matter of range (and re-sizing, and its associated pitfalls) that the OP was questioning. So in this case I'd say GUID is *not* the right tool for the job, as identifiers typically need only be unique *to one table*.

Comment: @EricLippert: do you think that in general it's better to use a GUID or an int for database keys?

Comment: @frenchie: I think Yuck's comment above is spot on. Do you need *global* uniqueness or *local* uniqueness? If you need *global* uniqueness, use a guid. If you don't need global uniqueness, if you just need a primary key for the table, then an integer will suffice.

Comment: The advantage of GUID, is you don't need access to the table to generate an identifier that's "guaranteed" unique in the table. So it's the choice for scaled and distributed systems. The problem compared to bigint is it takes up more space and indexes on it are likely to be ineffecicient compared to an int type.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: You don't need access to the table if you let the database generate it for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I'm using an int for now and I'll upgrade the key of some tables to long ints. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason. Sorry I wasn't clear. What I meant was you don't need any table or better yet a specific table / sequence, like you would with an integer identity and still have a guarantee of uniqueness. You can also generate them clientside and use them, which can reduce a fair amount of complexity. Like everything else in life , it;s not free though. :(

Comment: @Yuck because range is huge as you said, but Guid offers easy syncronization for remote created records, not sequential which can makes remote attack harder in case of url fuzzing, useful for replications scenarii. But bigint can do the job, it always depends of your needs!